# Find and rename all files in directory matching a certain pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x, glob, file-rename

I'm attempting to write a program that will loop through every subfolder, find and rename all the files that match a given pattern in the filename. The files are all .jpg files and have the following patter:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]_UsersfirstnameUserslastname[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg
```

so for instance one folders would have the following:

```
452_AlexBobenko002.jpg
452_AlexBobenko003.jpg
452_AlexBobenko007.jpg
```

Then it would go to another folder where the following files exists:

```
834_CatDonald001.jpg
...
834_CatDonlad126.jpg
```

I would like to rename the files so that there would be an underscore after the last letter and before the last set of 3 digits. So the patter would go from:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]_UsersfirstnameUserslastname[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg
```

to

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]_UsersfirstnameUserslastname_[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg
```

and from the above example I would have:

```
452_AlexBobenko002.jpg --> 452_AlexBobenko_002.jpg
452_AlexBobenko003.jpg --> 452_AlexBobenko_003.jpg
452_AlexBobenko007.jpg --> 452_AlexBobenko_007.jpg
```

and

```
834_CatDonald001.jpg --> 834_CatDonald_001.jpg
...
834_CatDonlad126.jpg --> 834_CatDonald_126.jpg
```

So far I have been able to locate the desired files with the following:

```
path = mydir
folders    = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path) if  filename.startswith('EMP-')]
subfolders = [[] for i in range(len(folders))]

# Will populate the empty sublist of subfolders with the contents of each distinct folder
for i in range(len(folders)):
   subfolders[i] = [subfolder for subfolder in os.listdir(path +'\\%s' %folders[i])]

for z_1 in range(len(folders)):
    for z_2 in range(len(subfolders[z_1])):
        if os.path.isdir(path + '\\%s\\%s' % (folders[z_1], subfolders[z_1][z_2])) == True:
            for file in glob.glob(path + '\\%s\\%s\\[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.jpg' % (folders[z_1], subfolders[z_1][z_2])):
                #rename(file)
```

I really have no clue how to rename them

Comment: Given that you know that the original files end with a pattern of 3 digits plus a `.jpg` extension, you can just grab that part with string indexing: `filename[:-7] + '_' + filename[-7:]`.

Comment: thanks, I was trying to come up with a method using regex or fnmatch, I didn't think it wold be that simple.